# Multiplication of tensor and vector

Tags: matrices, reference-request, tensor-products, tensors

How do we mulitiply a multidimensional array $A_{n\times n\times n}$ and a vector $v_n$ (indices denote dimensions)? Can you kindly give suggestions or references?

Answer (score 1):

In the end for a couple of tensors $A_{ijk}$ and $v^s$ (described by components) their juxtaposition 
$$A_{ijk}v^s,$$ 
give you the components of a new tensor, whose rank is the sum of their ranks, this juxtaposition is only a plain multiplication of numbers.

One can get the components of a rank two if we "contract" some indexes as in $A_{ijs}v^s$.

Comment: Since a rank 2 tensor multiplies a vector ($A_{n\times n}\cdot v_n$) leads to a vector, isn't it should be a $n\times n$ matrix for my question $A_{n\times n\times n}\cdot v_n$?

Comment: we have  $A_{ij}v^s$ for a **rank 3**, but $A_{is}v^s$ for a **rank 1**... also $A_{ijk}v^s$ for a **rank 4**, but $A_{ijs}v^s$ for a **rank 2**.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at hand. In this topic @user143763 can find a proper answer, if he or she is still looking for it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953185/tensors-and-matrices-multiplication

Comment: @miquelramirez... Well, by doing the contraction $$B_{ij}:=A_{ijs}v^s,$$ a rank two tensor, there are also another two more, rank two tensors $$C_{ik}:=A_{isk}v^s,$$ and $$D_{jk}:=A_{sjk}v^s.$$

Comment: Just link to the technical report by Kolda & Bader mentioned in the other answer. Your "answer" is assuming a fair bit of knowledge that - in my reading - the OP didn't have and gives 0 insight about how the calculation actually is done.