# Using the chain rule correctly with matrices as the partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, tensors

I hope this question fits the math.stackexchange environment.

I try to understand how a Neural Network calculates the derivatives along the Backpropagation with the chain rule correctly, but I struggle a bit with some explanations with tensors.

## What I have calculated

For my example I used the last hidden layer of a small network with only three neurons on the hidden layer and two outputs, which results in:

$$
W = \begin{bmatrix}w_{1,1} & w_{1,2} & w_{1,3} \\w_{2,1} & w_{2,2} & w_{2,3} \end{bmatrix}, \vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}, \vec{z} = \begin{bmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\vec{a} = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
with
$$
z_1 = a_1\cdot w_{1,1} + a_2\cdot w_{1,2} + a_3\cdot w_{1,3} + b_1
$$
and
$$
z_2 = a_1\cdot w_{2,1} + a_2\cdot w_{2,2} + a_3\cdot w_{2,3} + b_1
$$
or in vectorform:
$$
\vec{z} = W \cdot \vec{a} + \vec{b}
$$
The loss function cross-entropy is used which results in the derivative:

$$
\nabla_\vec{z} Loss = \vec{q} - \vec{1}_y
$$
with $\vec{q}$ being the vector presentation of the softmax-function and $\vec{1}_y$ being a zero vector with a $1$ at position $y$.

So on this Basis I started to calculate the partial derivatives, beginning with the bias-vector:
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{z}}{\partial \vec{b}} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial b_1}=1 && \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial b_2}=0 \\  \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial b_1}=0 && \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial b_2}=1  \end{bmatrix}
$$
With this Jacobi-Matrix I am able to use the chainrule $\biggl(\frac{\partial \vec{z}}{\partial \vec{b}}\biggr)^\top \nabla_\vec{z} Loss$ to calculate the upgrade vector for $\vec{b}$

If I do now the similar with the Matrix $W$ I result in a tensor which I represent in two seperate matrices:
$$
\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial W} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{1,1}}=a_1 && \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{1,2}}=a_2 && \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{1,3}}=a_3 \\  \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{2,1}}=0 && \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{2,2}}=0 && \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial w_{2,3}}=0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial W} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{1,1}}=0 && \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{1,2}}=0 && \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{1,3}}=0 \\  \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{2,1}}=a_1 && \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{2,2}}=a_2 && \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial w_{2,3}}=a_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

## Where I now struggle

I now from different source (Andrew Ng, Goodfellow) the result of the following calculation, which should result in the upgrade matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \cdot (q_1 - 0) & a_2 \cdot (q_1 - 0) & a_2 \cdot (q_1 - 0) \\ a_1 \cdot (q_2 - 1) & a_2 \cdot (q_2 - 1) & a_2 \cdot (q_2 - 1) \end{bmatrix}
$$
if $y=1$ (zero-based indexing)

My first problem I have is to calculate the Transpose of a tensor, since I am not able to figure how to define which axis is responsible for the transpose.

My second problem is the calculation of $\biggl(\frac{\partial \vec{z}}{\partial W}\biggr)^\top \nabla_\vec{z} Loss$. I am able to visualize at least in my mind which calculations are necessary to get the result shown above, but I think the dot-product is not the right product to get this result.

Since my background is neither maths or physics, I had problems to figure out how to calculate with tensor correctly but I wanted to show a more accurate representation, than the shortcuts which I see plenty on "TowardsDataSience" and Co.

Comment: Today I figured out via this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615619/multiplication-of-tensor-and-vector and finally via this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953185/tensors-and-matrices-multiplication that the $n-mode$ product actually produces what I want. Can anybody confirm this?